# Can ELMAH work with Oracle.ManagedDataAccess?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, odp.net, elmah

I have ASP.NET MVC project which connects to Oracle database using Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll, so I do not need to install Oracle client on any machine where application is deployed. Is there any option to configure ELMAH to use Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll? 
In other way, as I understand, ELMAH can use only Oracle client?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The newest version of the Oracle error logger for ELMAH, actually supports both Oracle Client and Oracles own .NET client:

https://github.com/JamesDriscoll/ELMAH.OracleErrorLog/blob/master/src/OracleErrorLog.cs#L429

There's no 2.x NuGet package of ELMAH, containing this error logger yet. You can clone the ELMAH repository from GitHub and distribute it through source control, internal NuGet server, or MyGet. Alternatively, you can create your own error log implementation: [Writing custom error loggers for ELMAH](https://blog.elmah.io/writing-custom-error-loggers-for-elmah/).

Answer (score 1):

This is code from my web.config.

```
<sectionGroup name="elmah">
      <section name="security" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.SecuritySectionHandler, Elmah" />
      <section name="errorLog" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorLogSectionHandler, Elmah" />
      <section name="errorMail" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorMailSectionHandler, Elmah" />
      <section name="errorFilter" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterSectionHandler, Elmah" />
</sectionGroup>

<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <add name="ErrorLog" type="Elmah.ErrorLogModule, Elmah" preCondition="managedHandler" />
      <add name="ErrorMail" type="Elmah.ErrorMailModule, Elmah" preCondition="managedHandler" />
      <add name="ErrorFilter" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterModule, Elmah" preCondition="managedHandler" />
    </modules>
<system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="ELMAH" verb="POST,GET,HEAD" path="elmah.axd" type="Elmah.ErrorLogPageFactory, Elmah" preCondition="integratedMode" />
    </handlers>
</system.webServer>
<elmah>
    <security allowRemoteAccess="1" />
    <errorLog type="Elmah.OracleErrorLog, Elmah" connectionStringName="elmah-oracle" schemaOwner="" />
</elmah>
<add name="elmah-oracle" connectionString="USER ID=...;DATA SOURCE=...;PASSWORD=..." providerName="Oracle.DataAccess.Client" />
```

Comment: Try removing the providerName attribute.

Comment: And are you running with a custom build using the latest code from GitHub?

Comment: I run latest version from NuGet (1.2.2).

Comment: That won't work. As I wrote previously, only the newest code on GitHub supports Oracle's .NET client. The newest code isn't available on NuGet yet. If you want it to work, you will need to clone the newest code and build it yourself.

Comment: It works!! As you suggested I use version from GitHub and additional settings for DbProviderFactory from this link http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/downloads/odpnet-managed-nuget-121021-2405792.txt